# at the end of 'for loop' to trigger event

Tags: objective-c, macos

I used code below to copy a list of files to another place, It works

```
for (NSInteger i = 0;i<= urlArray1.count - 1;i++ ){

    NSURL url1=[self urlForBookmark:[urlArray1 objectAtIndex:i];
    NSURL url2=[self urlForBookmark:[urlArray2 objectAtIndex:i];

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:url1 toURL:url2 error:&e];



}

labelA:
```

what I hope to get is when the code completed all files copy, something will be triggered.

But it look likes the code works in Async mode which means that labelA will be triggered immediately,

even the copy procedure is still working.

your comment welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, its a synchronous operation, if you go to [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1412957-copyitematurl?language=objc):

> Copies the file at the specified URL to a new location synchronously.

and returns a boolean with the result of the operation.